# How to add a header to h:selectmanylistbox (In code)

Tags: jsf

I'm doing this from code but it should be equivalent to jsp..

Trying to have a header for a selectmanylistbox. (I'm looking for the same look as a header on a table column would have.)
What I'm trying now is: (The relevant code)

```
HtmlSelectManyListbox list = new HtmlSelectManyListbox();

HtmlOutputText headerText = new HtmlOutputText();
headerText.setValue("Testing");

list.getFacets().put("header",headerText);
```

The list doesn't show a header.
Anyone knows why??

Thanks!

Comment: According the TLD of the standard implementation, the `h:selectManyListbox` doesn't support any facets. How does the JSP equivalent look like?

Comment: Well... If h:selectmanylistbox doesn't support the header facet than it makes sense that this didn't work.
How would you add a custom header? I tried with a panelgrid and 1 column to add an outputtext, but it looks detached and not pretty..

Comment: As asked by BalusC, what is the graphical representation you are looking for for this `<select>` component?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious.  I'm looking for the same look as a header on a table column would have.

Comment: It's not obvious if you aren't able to do it straight in the JSP :) Your question really needs to be reframed.

Comment: If I was not clear enough: it would help if you post the exact JSP code here you would like to end up with, then we can suggest answers how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Oh.. Thanx. But I was not looking for the JSP way to do it.
I know how to implement it in JSP but it wouldn't work there too since (I know realize) h:selectManyListBox does not support any facet tag (And specifically not Header). Instead, I was looking for an alternative way to add a heaedr to the component. 
Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:selectManyListBox>` does not support any `<f:facet>`. So you will have to create it manually. In fact, it really depends on what you are looking for.

You can use a `<div>` and play with the `CSS` classes to have your required look and feel, or use a [`<fieldset>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_fieldset.asp) HTML tag:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your choice:</legend>
    <h:selectManyListBox value="...">
        <f:selectItems value="..."/>
    </h:selectManyListBox>
</fieldset>
```